# Reading Multiple Orc Files in Pig

Tags: apache-pig, glob, orc

I am trying to read/Load multiple Orc files present in a directory Using pig's OrcStorage(). I tried to use glob technique but that was not working for me and throwing error saying file dose not exist, where as it is available.Please let me know how i can implement this functionality in pig.

**Sample Files Used:**

```
hadoop fs -ls /sandbox/sandbox28/pig_demo/input/ORC/data_dt={2015111900,2015111901}
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 as303e hdfs     302986 2015-11-19 05:12 /sandbox/sandbox28/pig_demo/input/ORC/data_dt=2015111900/000000_0
-rw-r--r--   3 as303e hdfs     302986 2015-11-19 05:12 /sandbox/sandbox28/pig_demo/input/ORC/data_dt=2015111900/000001_0
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 as303e ksndbx28     302986 2015-11-25 04:34 /sandbox/sandbox28/pig_demo/input/ORC/data_dt=2015111901/000000_0
-rw-r--r--   3 as303e ksndbx28     302986 2015-11-25 04:34 /sandbox/sandbox28/pig_demo/input/ORC/data_dt=2015111901/000001_0
```

**Code Used:**

```
A = load '/sandbox/sandbox28/pig_demo/input/ORC/data_dt={2015111900,2015111901}' Using OrcStorage();

B= limit A 2;

DUMP B;
```

**Error log:**

```
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: B: Store(hdfs://localhost:8020/tmp/temp666047359/tmp808921130:org.apache.pig.impl.io.InterStorage) - scope-5 Operator Key: scope-5): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: B: Limit - scope-4 Operator Key: scope-4): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2081: Unable to setup the load function.
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:316)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POStore.getNextTuple(POStore.java:159)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.fetch.FetchLauncher.runPipeline(FetchLauncher.java:161)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.fetch.FetchLauncher.launchPig(FetchLauncher.java:81)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:278)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1390)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1375)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1034)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: B: Limit - scope-4 Operator Key: scope-4): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2081: Unable to setup the load function.
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:316)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POLimit.getNextTuple(POLimit.java:122)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:307)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2081: Unable to setup the load function.
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POLoad.getNextTuple(POLoad.java:131)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:307)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:8020/sandbox/sandbox28/pig_demo/input/ORC/data_dt={2015111900,2015111901}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:961)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcNewInputFormat.getSplits(OrcNewInputFormat.java:121)
        at org.apache.pig.impl.io.ReadToEndLoader.init(ReadToEndLoader.java:190)
        at org.apache.pig.impl.io.ReadToEndLoader.<init>(ReadToEndLoader.java:146)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POLoad.setUp(POLoad.java:99)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POLoad.getNextTuple(POLoad.java:127)
        ... 25 more
```

Comment: I had the same issue du to the comma, could you try a solution that not use a comma : `A = load '/sandbox/sandbox28/pig_demo/input/ORC/data_dt=201511190*' Using OrcStorage();` ?  I you use a comma, I think you'll have to load : `'hdfs://localhost:8020/sandbox/sandbox28/pig_demo/input/ORC/data_dt=2015111900,hdfs://localhost:8020/sandbox/sandbox28/pig_demo/input/ORC/data_dt=2015111901'`

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @antonybrd Unfortunately  i cannot use wild card option data_dt=201511190* because there will be lot of source folders which i would have processed already!!. I am trying to load only delta changes. Now i am planning to implement a solution which will generate pig code using some other wrapper program  with multiple load statements